# Why apps within same solution get different AppData path

Tags: .net, vb.net, userappdatapath

I have a one solution, and two projects inside it. Both projects exists in the same namespace, e.g. *MyCompanyName*. When I call

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData
```

this method returns two different paths. 
First path is *C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\MyCompanyName*, 
second path is *C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\MyCompanyFullName*.

I should know, why? Thanks!

Comment: Are they running under different user accounts? E.g. is one an Asp.Net application running under IIS? (I think there are also some oddities with "modern" windows apps, UWP and the like)

Comment: Did you ever consider letting us know what those paths are?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever no, both WPF apps, compiled under .NET 3.5 sp1, running on win 7, one user account.

Comment: @jmcilhinney first path is C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\MyCompanyName, second path is C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\MyCompanyFullName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer. If in project properties, in the assembly information, in the field "Organization" set company name, so current user application data is according to this name. If company name is missed, the current user application data is according to root namespace.